# CSS - Nested DIV : Clear Sub Styles

Tags: css

I am sure sure if this is even possible due to the nature of CSS and being cascading, but I will try anyway.

I am creating a Terms and Conditions box which will contain some key elements that the user will select. Since the T&C's will have form components (radio buttons, check boxes). I don't really want to go through the trouble of putting it into an IFrame and getting the user input that way.

I figured using a  with the overflow: auto property added, I could create an scrolling box with the T&C's and have the user select their options that way.

Well, because the T&C's have some mark up which would be directly affected by the sites css, I need to figure out a way to have this div not use the main CSS of the site.

Here is some sample code which would be similar to the approach I am trying:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div
        {
            border: solid 1px #000;
        }
        div small
        {
            font-size: 17pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="overflow: auto; width: 500px; height: 300px;">
        <small>This is small text</small>
        <div>
            <small>This is small text</small> 
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
            elit. Donec vulputate mi sed nisl blandit sed porttitor massa fringilla.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result of this is a pretty little black box with some text and then a sub box with more text and the key item in here is the text wrapped in `<small/>`.

Is there a way to have anything under a certain div NOT inherit the CSS? Maybe I need to take a completely different approach with this.

Thought? Ideas? Suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of working directly with tag names, keep two sets of classes ("inner" and "outer") and work with those.

So you can have a `div.inner` definition, and a `div.outer` definition, and work on them separately. The `inner` one would have to explicitly undo the settings `outer` has, though.

Something like

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="outer">Some content. <small>Small text.</small></div>
  <div class="inner container">
     <small>Blah blah blah</small>
     More content
  </div>
</div>
```

And in your CSS define whatever you need,

```
div.outer {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
div.outer small {
   font: 17pt;
}
div.inner {
   border: none;
}
div.inner small {
   font: 15pt;
}
div.container {
   overflow: auto;
   width: 500px;
   height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Okay, this is what I feared. So if my sub content has a ton of different tags that would be directly changed from the css, I would need to create the CSS classes as described above to change all my tags... I am sad, but the first step towards grief is denial.

Answer (score 0):

don't think there is a way to not inherit css. i think the only way is to 'reset' all the styles set on its parents explicitly. see eg http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/ for a list of default properties.

Answer (score 0):

There is, as second notes, no way to inherently prevent the cascade of styles, it's the cascade that defines CSS after all. So you are reduced to using the `.inner` and `.outer` approach that Welbog suggested.

So you're reduced to defining your styles for the main document as you normally would. However to override those styles for the same elements under the T&C div you would have to explicitly override/re-style. You could use two stylesheets to retain clarity, but you'd have to remember, in the `t_and_c.css` to explicitly preface every declaration with the id of the enclosing div, for example:

```
#t&c p {...}

#t&c a:link,
#t&c a:visited {...}
```